# How to execute Numpy functions on a cluster?

Tags: python, numpy, mpi

I have been experiencing with MPI in Python through mpi4py. And it's working amazingly well to parallelize some code I developed. However I rely heavily on Numpy for matrix manipulation. I have a question regarding the usage of Numpy with MPI.

Let's take for instance de dot function in Numpy. Let's say I have 2 huge matrices A and B and I want to compute their matrix product A*B:

`numpy.dot(A, B)`

I would like to know how to spread this function call over the whole cluster. I can chunk B (columnwise) into smaller matrices and spread the matrix product on the cluster nodes and therefore regroup the result. However it seems like a bad workaround. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: Typically, running operations in parallel with MPI first means to distribute the data accordingly - which is a more complex question than just running an operation with shared memory and threads. We know too little about your application to really discuss this.